# Need to predict account activity based on history

Tags: time-series, predictive-modeling

I have three datasets, one containing app status information, the second containing account info, and the third being activity logs for the past couple years or so.  The activity logs contain records of each transaction, where each row has a consumer ID, timestamp, amount spent, etc.  The account info has additional customer information for each ID such as age and location data.  Finally, the app data contains registration date, consumer ID, and a status of either active or inactive.

My goal is to see if I can predict activity for each ID based on their transaction history.  My intuition says that a simple regression model or decision forest won't work because it's theoretically a time-dependent problem.  However, the only time-aware solution I know of would be RNNs, which pose another issue since the transactions associated with each ID would effectively be their own dataset.

How would I predict activity based on ID history, but be able to generalize across any ID?  The initial criteria for "activity" are simply "visits at least once a month."